# Forçar atualização da página de checkout woocomerce

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, woocommerce

Oi.
Minha loja não atualiza o valor do pedido quando altero método de pagamento ...
Como eu posso forçar esta atualização no ***functions PHP*** ou ***jquery script*** / *ajax* etc?
*woocomerce atualiza a página no ajax*, mas isso não funciona corretamente se eu usar descontos para um método de pagamento específico, pois ao atualizar a forma de pagamento o valor não está sendo atualizando corretamente, tenho que atualizar a janela para que isso seja possível.
Eu preciso que a janela atualize quando altero os *radios buttons* das formas de pagamentos.
Obrigado

**Edit**

aqui a função do método de pagamento do Woocomerce

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}
?>
<li class="wc_payment_method payment_method_<?php echo $gateway->id; ?>">
    <input   id="payment_method_<?php echo $gateway->id; ?>" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $gateway->id ); ?>" <?php checked( $gateway->chosen, true ); ?> data-order_button_text="<?php echo esc_attr( $gateway->order_button_text ); ?>" />

    <label for="payment_method_<?php echo $gateway->id; ?>">
        <?php echo $gateway->get_title(); ?> <?php echo $gateway->get_icon(); ?>
    </label>
    <?php if ( $gateway->has_fields() || $gateway->get_description() ) : ?>
        <div class="payment_box payment_method_<?php echo $gateway->id; ?>" <?php if ( ! $gateway->chosen ) : ?>style="display:none;"<?php endif; ?>>
            <?php $gateway->payment_fields(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</li>
```

Comment: post seu código ate o momento para que alguém te ajudar...

Comment: Obrigado. Adicionei um treço da função que verifica, porém é complicado postar todos arquivos que envolvem isso, mas o código do woocomerce é open souce, aqui o link do git https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce